# workaround ORA-01795 error programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am getting a ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error for my project that I wish to solve in the code.  Basically I am working with 2 databases (one sql server, one oracle) both of which I only have read only access (creating temp tables is not possible).

What i do is select a lists of IDs from DB 1, then search for the information corresponding to those IDs from DB2.  This is where I use the 'IN' Clause, which contains more than 1000 IDs.  I want to know how I can solve this programmatically- this is what i have so far (pseudo code, my real code is much more complex with too many wrappers):

```
1. "select ID from table 1 where some condition." [Database 1 conn]
2. string IDs = "";
   while (rset.next)
   {
        IDs += rset.getcolumn("ID");
        IDs += ", ";
   }
   ID.Remove(ID.length - 2); //at this point I have all IDs separated by a comma.
3. "select * from table 2 where ID IN (" +IDs+ ")" //this is where the error occurs.
```

Is there a workaround to this?  One of the idea I have is to split the IDs string into a string array with 999 IDs in each cell, then have a for loop in the sql query string to add in OR conditions, but am having trouble with the code.

Comment: There are many solutions to this already on the web.  Do some searching.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pretty standard solutions, 1 being a temporary table if you have rights to create one and then doing a where id in ( select id from temptable).  The second is similar to what you suggest, do 999 and then add a union all for the next 999 and so on.

```
 select * from t1 where Id in (1,2 ... ,1000)
 union all
 select * from t2 where Id in (1001,1002,...)
```